# SVGでwindowsformアプリケーションのリストボックス等を作るには？

Tags: javascript, html5, svg

現在作っているWebサイトで大きなsvg画像を表示するページがあります。
(htmlにインラインsvgを埋め込んでいます。)
そのページのsvgタグ内に、windowsformアプリケーションのオブジェクト(例：リストボックス、コンボボックス等)を作成することは可能でしょうか？
svgでオブジェクトを作ることが難しい場合は、svgタグ内にオブジェクトを追加する方法でもかまいません。

foreignObjectタグを使って、svgタグにhtml要素のオブジェクトを埋め込むことは試みましたが、ブラウザの種類毎に挙動が異なったり、埋め込んだhtml要素そのものが表示されなかったりと、うまくいきませんでした。

追記：bodyタグ内にはsvgタグのみ挿入し、svgタグの子孫要素として機能を実現したいと考えています。

Comment: SVGの内部ではなく上にHTMLのselect要素を重ねて配置するという方針はどうでしょうか。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。ご意見参考にさせていただきます。
今回、条件としてbodyタグ内にsvgタグのみ挿入し、その子孫要素として機能を実現したいと考えています。
明記しておらず申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 1):

昔の質問ですが、同じ疑問でたどり着いた方のために回答しておきます。
foreignObjectを調べてみてください。